# Pythonic way of determining if the current element is the first or last element of a generator?

Tags: python

I am going through a generator, whats the Pythonic way of determining if the current element is the first or last element of a generator, given that they need special care?

thanks

basically generating tags, so i have items like

```
<div class="first">1</div>
<div>...</div>
<div class="last">n</div>
```

so i would like to keep the last item in loop?

Comment: What do you mean when you say they need special care?

Comment: @bluepnume He wants to run a function or process on them I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an enumerate-like generator that skips ahead one; it returns -1 for the last element.

```
>>> def annotate(gen):
...     prev_i, prev_val = 0, gen.next()
...     for i, val in enumerate(gen, start=1):
...         yield prev_i, prev_val
...         prev_i, prev_val = i, val
...     yield '-1', prev_val
>>> for i, val in annotate(iter(range(4))):
...     print i, val
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
-1 3
```

It can't tell whether the generator passed to it is "fresh" or not, but it still tells you when the end is nigh:

```
>>> used_iter = iter(range(5))
>>> used_iter.next()
0
>>> for i, val in annotate(used_iter):
...     print i, val
... 
0 1
1 2
2 3
-1 4
```

Once an iterator is used up, it raises `StopIteration` as usual.

```
>>> annotate(used_iter).next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in annotate
StopIteration
```

Comment: As it is, this gives an error when passed an object without a `next()` method. To avoid that, you could add `gen = iter(gen)` at the beginning of `annotate`.

Answer (score 3):

The way that I do this is similar to some of the other answers here - but I do it this way, as a matter of preference.  Maybe it will suit your preferences too.

With my function below, I can write code like this:

```
values = [10, 11, 12, 13]
for i, val, isfirst, islast in enumerate2(values):
  if isfirst:
    print 'BEGIN...', val
  elif islast:
    print val, '... END'
  else:
    print val
```

Here is the function definition:

```
def enumerate2(iterable_):
  it = iter(iterable_)
  try:
    e = it.next()
    isfirst = True
    i = 0
    try:
      while True:
        next_e = it.next()
        yield (i, e, isfirst, False)
        i += 1
        isfirst = False
        e = next_e
    except StopIteration:
      yield (i, e, isfirst, True)
  except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first, use a flag to tell whether or not you've processed any. For the last, hold the next value in a variable, and if there are no more then that's the last one.

Comment: It should be possible to create a function that does this generically. I'm surprised nothing exists in itertools.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for the first element:

```
for n, item in enumerate(generator()):
  if n == 0:
    # item is first
# out of the loop now: item is last
```

Comment: is there no way to do the last item in loop?

Comment: Even the generator might not now until it is too late.

Comment: @Timmy: it would be really helpful to know why you need to know this, there's probably a way to do what you're looking for without checking for the last item within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a sequence, example:

```
>>> gen = (x for x in range(5))
>>> L = list(gen)
>>> L[0]
0
>>> L[-1]
4
>>>
```

If you need to do this during the loop:

```
>>> gen = (x for x in range(5))
>>> L = list(gen)
>>> for idx, item in enumerate(L):
...    if idx == 0:
...        print(u'{item} is first'.format(item=item))
...    if idx == len(L) - 1:
...        print(u'{item} is last'.format(item=item))
...
0 is first
4 is last
>>>
```

Clearly, this is not the solution, if *you* are the one who created the generator, and need it to stay that way (for memory savings), but if you don't care, this is more Pythonic per se than setting flags (which is implicit at best, sine it relies on the last element during iteration persisting), and `enumerate` won't get you any closer to finding the last element.

Comment: thx, i dun just need the first and last element, just that processing them specially

Comment: thx, i knew to do it this way, dont like it, but its probbably best

Comment: You don't have to make it into a list. You can create a generator that [looks ahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983265/pythonic-way-of-determining-if-the-current-element-is-the-first-or-last-element-o/5983613#5983613).

Comment: @Timmy - I hate to give up points :) but the best answer is @senderle's (sine it does exactly what you want directly to a generator, in a Pythonic way).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it violates all generator's advantages, but if your iterable is not large, you should use:

```
list(gener)[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about potentially large collections built dynamically, so that you don't want to temporarily place it into a single data structure, here's a different way:

```
FLAGMASK_FIRST = 1
FLAGMASK_LAST = 2

def flag_lastfirst(collection):
    first_flag = FLAGMASK_FIRST
    first = True
    index = 0
    for element in collection:
        if not first:
            yield index, first_flag, current
            index += 1
            first_flag = 0
        current = element
        first = False
    if not first:
        yield index, first_flag | FLAGMASK_LAST, current

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for k in flag_lastfirst(l):
    print(k)
```

The function will produce a sequence of tuples, one for each element from the original collection.

The contents of the tuple:

- `t[0]` = 0-based index
- `t[1]` = bitwise flags, FLAGMASK_FIRST is present if the element is the first element, FLAGMASK_LAST is present if the element is the last element
- `t[2]` = The original element from the original collection

Sample output from the code above:

```
 +-- 0-based index
 v
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(2, 0, 3)
(3, 2, 4)
    ^  ^
    |  +-- the element from the original collection
    |
    +-- 1 means first, 2 means last,
        3 means both first and last, 0 is everything else
```

I'm sure there are nicer ways to build this kinda thing, but this is my contribution anyway.