# Detect last iteration over dictionary.iteritems() in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a simple way to detect the last iteration while iterating over a dictionary using `iteritems()`?

Comment: May I ask why this is important? Dictionaries in Python have no defined iteration order, so what makes the last iteration special?

Comment: in general, `'somestring'.join(d.iteritems())` or the `pprint` module should handle the most common issue reason people wish to do this

Comment: Why not using OrderedDict (Dictionary that remembers insertion order) instead?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y I'm constructing the WHERE part of an SQL query from a dict, so in a sense this also falls in the category @ninjagecko suggested. Based on the comments, I think the most efficient way would be to construct the SQL syntax by altering the string representation of the dict.

Comment: Found a nice solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1630350/804616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of [this broader question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5983265/577088). My suggestion was to create an [enumerate-like generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983265/pythonic-way-of-determining-if-the-current-element-is-the-first-or-last-element-o/5983613#5983613) that returns -1 on the last item:

```
def annotate(gen):
    prev_i, prev_val = 0, gen.next()
    for i, val in enumerate(gen, start=1):
        yield prev_i, prev_val
        prev_i, prev_val = i, val
    yield '-1', prev_val
```

Add `gen = iter(gen)` if you want it to handle sequences as well as generators.

Answer (score 17):

There is an ugly way to do this:

```py
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(your_dict.items()):
    if i == len(your_dict)-1:
        # do special stuff here
```

But you should really consider if you need this. I am almost certain that there is another way.

Comment: assuming the dictionary doesn't change size

Comment: @ninjagecko: If it does, you're screwed anyway. Resizing collections while iterating over them is a punishable offense for a reason, it creates highly confusing and meaningless results and is even more rarely useful than `eval`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this late, but here's how I've solved this issue:

```
dictItemCount = len(dict)
dictPosition = 1
for key,value in dict
    if(dictPosition = dictItemCount):
        print 'last item in dictionary'
    dictPosition += 1
```

Comment: Note that this should read:
if(dictPosition==dictItemCount):

Answer (score 2):

```
it = spam_dict.iteritems()
try:
    eggs1 = it.next()
    while True:
        eggs2 = it.next()
        do_something(eggs1)
        eggs1 = eggs2
except StopIteration:
    do_final(eggs1)
```

Quick and quite dirty. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: -1.  This is functionally equivalent to a much simpler for loop:  `for eggs in spam_dict.iteritems(): do_something(eggs)` and then after the for loop: `do_final(eggs)`.

Comment: Removing my -1 because of the correction.  However, I'm not sure why you felt compelled to offer an answer given that Space_C0wb0y's ugly answer is less ugly and easier to understand.

Comment: By the way, if the dictionary is empty, the call to `do_final(eggs1)` raises a `NameError`.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure myself. It's just a different way to do the job. Perhaps don't relying on the length makes it more stable.

Answer (score 2):

as others have stated, dictionaries have no defined order, so it's hard to imagine why you would need this, but here it is

```
last = None
for current in your_dict.iteritems():
  if last is not None:
    # process last
  last = current

# now last contains the last thing in dict.iteritems()
if last is not None: # this could happen if the dict was empty
  # process the last item
```

Comment: this can work, but you have to do `MY_NONE = object()` and use `MY_NONE` rather than `None`, or else this will fail if the iterator contains `None`

Comment: iteritems returns kev/value tuples, so it can't have a None.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue, I thought this was the most elegant solution because it allowed you to write `for i,value,isLast in lastEnumerate(...):`:

```
def lastEnumerate(iterator):
    x = list(iterator)
    for i,value in enumerate(x):
        yield i,value,i==len(x)-1
```

For example:

```
for i,value,isLast in lastEnumerate(range(5)):
    print(value)
    if not isLast:
        print(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach that makes the most sense is to wrap the loop in some call which contains a hook to call your post-iteration functionality afterwards.

This could be implemented as context manager and called through a 'with' statement or, for older versions of Python, you could use the old 'try:' ... 'finally:' construct.  It could also be wrapped in a class where the dictionary iteration is self dispatched (a "private" method) and the appendix code follows that in the public method.  (Understanding that the distension between public vs private is a matter of intention and documentation, not enforced by Python).

Answer (score 0):

The last item in a for loop hangs around after the for loop anyway:

```
for current_item in my_dict:
    do_something(current_item)

try:
    do_last(current_item)
except NameError:
    print "my_dict was empty"
```

Even if the name "current_item" is in use before the for loop, attempting to loop over an empty dict seems to have the effect of deleting current_item, hence the NameError

Answer (score 0):

You stated in an above comment that you need this to construct the WHERE clause of an SQL SELECT statement.  Perhaps this will help:

```
def make_filter(colname, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if '%' in value:
            return "%s LIKE '%s'" % (colname, value)
        else:
            return "%s = '%s'" % (colname, value)
    return "%s = %s" % (colname, value)

filters = {'USER_ID':'123456', 'CHECK_NUM':23459, 'CHECK_STATUS':'C%'}
whereclause = 'WHERE '+'\nAND '.join(make_filter(*x) for x in filters.iteritems())
print whereclause
```

which prints

```
WHERE CHECK_NUM = 23459
AND CHECK_STATUS LIKE 'C%'
AND USER_ID = '123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to enumerate your dict and compare the current iteration against the final one. Its easier to look at and understand in my opinion:

```
for n, (key, value) in enumerate(yourDict.items()):
    if yourDict[n] == yourDict[-1]:
        print('Found the last iteration!:', n)
```

OR you could just do something once the iteration is finished:

```
for key, value in yourDict.items():
    pass
else:
    print('Finished iterating over `yourDict`')
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you give us some details as to why and how your solution solves the problem in your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

No. When using an iterator you do not know anything about the position - actually, the iterator could be infinite.

Besides that, a dictionary is **not ordered**. So if you need it e.g. to insert commas between the elements you should take the items, sort them and them iterate over the list of `(key, value)` tuples. And when iterating over this list you can easily count the number of iterations and thus know when you have the last element.